# Segmentio destination BigQuery warehouse not displayed in consent manager window

Tags: google-bigquery, warehouse, cookieconsent, segment-io

I am using consent-manager package to configure Segmentio BigQuery destination, but its not reflecting in Website Data Collection Preferences window image below. Rest of the destinations like google analytics and Braze are displayed.

Please suggest.

Below is the destination array,

```js
'Analytics': {
               integrations: ['Hotjar','Google Analytics','Braze Web Mode (Actions)','BigQuery'],
               purpose: '',
             },
```

[image]